# What the number 1 or -1 means in an index of a string field?

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, if I had the following document:

```
{
name: "John Doe",
category: "Blue"
}
```

If I put an index in the category field for faster searches, what does the number mean when the field is a string?

```
db.people.createIndex({ category: 1 });
```

I mean, when I put the 1 or -1 in the index, it will index in alphabetical order, ascending or descending?

Comment: The 1 or -1 is just saying index on this field and if negative index descending or positive for ascending. See [create index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex) options for what's available.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere yeah, I know that it operates this way when the field is a number, but if the field is a string like the example document, ascending means alphabetical?

Comment: Yes, pretty much alphabetical - you can specify additional [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#option-for-collation) options.

Comment: 1 successful -1 unsuccessful

Comment: @dılosürücü I don't understand what you mean, successful and unsuccessful what? the query?

Answer (score 0):

From the MongoDB docs (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/):

```
db.collection.createIndex(keys, options)¶

keys    document    
A document that contains the field and value pairs where the field is the index key and the value describes the type of index for that field. For an ascending index on a field, specify a value of 1; for descending index, specify a value of -1. Starting in 3.6, you cannot specify * as the index name.
```

Thus in your example, you are creating an ascending index (1) on field `category`.